# Using a Trademarked name on my company slogan phrase

Tags: trademark

Can A new business  use a trademarked Company name in its business slogan phrase?

For example: "Stripe" is a trademarked name for a payment gateway company. Suppose a new business wants to use it in a business slogan as "The stripe of Bitcoin". Could Stripe successfully sue the new company for using such a slogan?

Comment: To clarify, you are using "strip" (or do you mean "stripe", incidentally?) specifically as a reference to this other company, rather than using something that coincidentally is their name?

Comment: I mean Stripe it was a typo... Thanks

Comment: Are you using "The Stripe of Bitcoin" in a way one might say "The Rolls-Royce of pencils"?

Comment: or  do you try to say "The Pelican of Pencils"? (pelican is a famous pen manufacturer, but they *also* make pencils)

Comment: There are many company slogans that contain other companies' trademarks.  "Fly the friendly skies": United Airlines.  Friendly: a US restaurant chain.  "Connecting people": Nokia.  People: a magazine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slogan such as "The Stripe of Bitcoin" might well be taken to indicate that the seller of a product or service is trading on the good reputation associates with the mark "stripe". If so, that would probably be a form of trademark infringement, assuming thst "Stripe" is protected as a trademark, unless the permission of the holder of the trademark "Stripe" was obtained. Payment processing and cryptocurrency handling are sufficiently closely related that customer confusion is possible.

Note that **competitive** use is generally permitted. One can, for example market a soft drink with the tag "*The cola that's better than Coke*" without permission from Coca-cola (which i doubt anyone would ever get). This is because when a marketer says "X is better than Y" no one reasonably thinks X is sponsored or approved by Y, nor will anyone be lead by this tag into thinking that X and Y are the same.

Other forms of ***nominative use*** are also allowed without permission from the trademark holder. For example, a computer component might have been advertised as: "*compatible with Intel Pentium*", as this is just using a trademark to name a related product, and does not imply affiliation or sponsorship.

But a tag such as "*The Rolls-Royce of pencils*" might be ruled to be infringing, even though Rolls does not, as far as I know, make pencils.

Note that the details of trademark law vary significantly from one country to another. Note further that trademarks protected in one country may not be protected in another. The question does not specify any jurisdiction, so no answer can refer to the particular country that the asker may have in mind.

Comment: We really need a canonical "what is a trademark" question.

Comment: Comparing advertisements as described above ("the cola that's better than coke") may be significantly restricted in some jurisdictions. In Germany, it needs to be objectively true to be allowed, which in this example can obviously not be proved.

Comment: @phoog What needs to be done to create such a canonical question and answer?

Comment: @PMF Interesting. Under US law a statement of opinion is permitted in such cases. Indeed even a provably false claim is not a trademark infringement, although it might well be the crime of false advertising. Can the relevant German law be found in English translation, preferably from an official source?

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Even in Germany, it's not about trademark (as far as I know, at least not mostly), but about unfair competition - there's a separate law, called "Gesetz gegen den unlauteren Wettbewerb (UWG)" for that. [Here](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_uwg/englisch_uwg.html#p0090) is the relevant article in english.

Comment: @PMF  thank you.

Comment: "What needs to be done?": someone can ask a new question, or we can choose an existing question, about the basic purpose and operation of trademark law, and then we would encourage moderators and regular users with the "close" privilege to close new questions as duplicates of that one.  There was a user who pushed this approach very passionately at [Travel.SE], but [one of the most-used canonical questions there](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13183/19400) became so complex that I don't think it's particularly helpful.  A basic overview of trademark shouldn't need such complexity, though.